# django queryset: select join with auth_user

Tags: django

This is probably a pretty n00b question, but i can't get it to work.

If i have following model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

How would i get a list of all entry-titles of the currently logged in user?
Something like:

```
list = Entry.objects.filter(users__????__contains = request.user)
```

?

Thanks in advance for helping me advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I believe it might be along the lines of:

```
list = Entry.objects.filter(users__id__exact = request.user.pk)
```

or

```
list = Entry.objects.filter(users = request.user)
```

I believe either of those should work. For more info on [many to many relationships](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) check out the Django docs.

Answer (score 2):

I find the following to be more elegant, but it's up to you.

```
request.user.entry_set.all()
```

EDIT: You shouldn't need to import the Entry model class every time you want to find entries associated with a user. Using user.entry_set avoids that hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with:

```
Entry.objects.filter(users=request.user)
```

Django will sort out the correct join with the M2M table and add a WHERE clause limiting it to the current user.

Answer (score 1):

```
Entry.objects.filter(users=request.user)
```

And there is an error in your code. *CharField* requires *max_length*.

Comment: nice observation, i removed it to un-clutter the example without thinking about that